# Can a CPU cache similar calculations?

Tags: memory, cpu, cache

When a CPU tries to access random memory it accessed recently, it's possible the memory data is still in the processor cache, and it can retrieve it from this cache. Using this technique, the CPU can avoid communication with the RAM, which would've been slower.

Is a CPU able to employ a similar technique for recent calculations? In other words, is a CPU able to see if it calculated a similar calculation before, and just resort to a cached result?

Comment: Hardware memoization has been proposed academically, but I am not aware of any implementation. Newton-Raphson division is one attractive target for memoization since division is expensive and NR already involves a table look-up for an approximate inverse and the tag would only need to be for one value. (Value prediction is a similar concept, but value prediction is speculative, checking the prediction with an actual result rather than determining a valid value by a tag comparison.)

Comment: Another vaguely related optimization that has been proposed academically involves trace caches (though a predecoded instruction cache could accomplish some of the proposed optimizations). These do not cache the results of computations but analyze the code stream and cache transformations of the code (sometimes depending on control flow, which might make them count as operand-based caching of "computation").

Comment: Caches are very specific depending on the CPU's hardware. You find Level 1 and 2 caches as well as separate instruction and data caches. What you describe sounds like a feature request to the programmer of a program.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU cache thinks in more granular than "calculations"; just as you wrote it deals with addresses whatever they contain.
However, programs/applications themselves can manage that kind of cache. For example, user defined functions of database servers can have the property of cached because UDF's usually mean a magnitude of workload that may be worth to avoid by storing and fetching previous results.

Answer (score 0):

There are three caches on a modern x86/x64 processor, L1, L2, and L3.

The L1 cache is split between an instruction cache, and a data cache. There is a correlation between the two, so the instruction at position x in the instruction cache corresponds to the result in position x of the data cache.  So yes, the CPU can feed a calculation result from the cache if the instruction is truly the same, but not if it's just *similar*.  In other words, 2+5 is not the same as 3+4 even though the result is identical.

The L2 cache is data only and can basically be thought of as super-fast RAM.

L3 is the same as L2, except that it's shared among all processor cores (each core has its own L1 and L2 caches).

---

Here are some other optimization techniques that also pertain to your question.

**Instruction Prefetching:** The CPU can read ahead in the pipeline and execute instructions before they are actually requested.  The results are cached so that the CPU can simply feed the results from the cache when the instruction finally arrives.

**Branch Prediction:** When the prefetcher sees a conditional jump instruction coming up (an If/Then statement in your code), it can decide which branch is more likely to be taken (or if possible, execute both branches in parallel) and pre-calculate the results.  If it guessed correctly (or if it executed both in parallel), then the result is simply fed from the cache.

**Out-Of-Order Execution:**  The instruction decoder can rearrange instructions in the prefetcher so that they execute in the order that is most efficient for the CPU.  The results are kept straight in the cache so they can be fed out in the correct order that the program expects.

**SIMD (Single Instruction, Multiple Data) Instructions:**  The CPU can perform the same calculation on multiple data points with a single instruction. For example, adding 5 to an each of an array of integers.  The CPU can carry out the instruction repetitively without having to decode the ADD instruction for every calculation.

---

There are *LOTS* of optimizations that modern CPUs do to improve performance, but also don't count out the influence of optimizing compilers. A good compiler knows the CPU architecture's strengths and weaknesses, and can optimize the code before it even reaches the CPU.  For example, a compiler might be able to know that two particular values never change throughout a program, so it can have the CPU calculate them *at compile time* and embed them right into the code rather than making the CPU do the work at runtime.  It could also know that a particular CPU is faster at reads than jumps, so it can hard-code the same data value 5 times rather than making the CPU do 5 jumps.

[Here's a good resource](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-the-cache-memory-works/5/) on how memory caches work.